# VueJS Axios pass Id token to a global header

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I took the back-end response token and store it in `store.js` as a state.
How do I pass that token value to the `main.js`? I do want to attach it to the Authorization header. This is my code.
**store.js**

```
state:{
idToken:"a sample id token"
  }
```

**main.js**

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']=
```

How do I pass that token value to the Authorization header.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shubham Patel You should watch changes of the returnToken. Then, do hearder reset in the watcher. The token refreshing should also be made with mutations.
Maybe something like:

**Main.js**:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'returnToken'
    ])
  },
  watch: {
    returnToken(newToken) {
      this.$axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = newToken
    }
  }
}
```

**Store.js**:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    idToken:"a sample id token"
  },
  getters: {
    returnToken: state => {
      return state.idToken
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateToken(state, {token}) {
      state.idToken = token
    }
  }
})
```

Then somewhare else:

```
let token = await loadToken()
store.commit('updateToken', {token})
```

Comment: Authorization header is undefined. Is there a way to check whether or not it successfully passed to the main .js page. Thank you! =)

Comment: @Pathum Samararathna I think there may be some requests called before any token-mutation committing. You can check the state through vue-devtools in the vuex tab. Maybe an eager initing is better. Wrap all root template with an if-flag and retrieve your token in the created-hook. Release the if-flag in the callback.

Comment: In vue-tools getters -> returnToken getter succefully get the idToken value. So it's clear that getter works correctly. Is there any way to see whether or not that token successfully come to the main.js (Like console.log kind of thing)

Comment: @Pathum Samararathna Maybe you can map the getter in the Vue instance and print it out on the page.

Comment: I'm junior developer I have no idea how to do so. Could you please demonstrate how to do that. Thank you. =)

Comment: @Pathum Samararathna Use {{returnToken}} on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a getter in Vuex which will return your current authentication token.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
   idToken:"a sample id token"
 },
 getters: {
    returnToken: state => {
      return state.idToken
    }
  }
})
```

Then import the getter using

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'returnToken'
    ])
  }
}
```

Then write

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']=this.returnToken()`

[Reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html)

Comment: When I try this.idTokenPass() it gives an error "TypeError: this.idTokenPass is not a function" Then I remove parenthesis and try then there is no errors in console but Authorization header is undefined. May it the reason I'm doing this inside main.js not in a vue component?